# In lean4 why is induction only rewriting the goal, and not the known facts?

Tags: lean4, beginner

When I do induction over a variable $x$ in lean 4, why isn't $x=0$ available as a fact in the base case of the induction? Without this fact, I can't rewrite other facts in order to make the induction work.

For example, if I run this:

```
structure Odds where
  lose : Nat
  win : Nat
def odds_leq (a b : Odds) : Bool := a.win * b.lose <= b.win * a.lose
infixl:45 " ≤ " => odds_leq
infixl:45 " <= " => odds_leq

theorem odds_leq_transitive (a b c: Odds) (ab : a <= b) (bc : b <= c) : a <= c := by
  unfold odds_leq
  unfold odds_leq at ab
  unfold odds_leq at bc
  simp
  simp at ab
  simp at bc
  induction a.win
  sorry
```

I get this proof state:

[image]

Which is notably lacking a line like `h : a.win = 0` in `case zero`. It also didn't rewrite `ab : a.win + b.lose <= b.win * a.lose` into `ab : 0 + b.lose <= b.win * a.lose`.

Comment: Why did you define `odd_leq` to be in `Bool` rather than `Prop`?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Due to not knowing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a comment about your definition. By defining `odds_leq` to map into `Bool` rather than `Prop` you are making your life difficult unecessarily, because you will have to prove things like `(odds_leq x y) = true` instead of just `odds_leq x y`. So I am going to change `Bool` to `Prop` on the assumption that you're just not paying attention, or are unfamiliar with the difference between `Prop` and `Bool`.

The `induction` tactic does not seem to be very good at inducting on a non-variable, in your case `a.win`. If you first take apart `a` so that it becomes `{lose := a₁, win := a₂}` then `induction a₂` will work as expected.

This should get you going:

```
structure Odds where
  lose : Nat
  win : Nat

def odds_leq (a b : Odds) : Prop := a.win * b.lose <= b.win * a.lose

infixl:45 " ≤ " => odds_leq

theorem odds_leq_transitive (a b c : Odds) (ab : a ≤ b) (bc : b ≤ c) : a ≤ c := by
  -- unfold odds_leq everywhere in one go
  unfold odds_leq at *
  -- we decompose a into {lose := a₁, win := a₂} to help induction
  cases a with | mk a₁ a₂ =>
    simp at * -- simplify everywhere
    induction a₂ -- now it works as expected
    case zero => simp
    case succ k IH => sorry -- you're on your own here
```

Comment: Thanks, the bool->prop advice is helpful.